# Display 2D array data in ViewPager2

Tags: android-studio, multidimensional-array, android-viewpager2

My 2D array has 5x3. In array I have stored id, name, image source string. I trying to put these values in Adapter to make newInstance, but all values in Fragment are passed as `null`.

My Adapter:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa) {
            super(fa);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

            if (position < q_question.length) {
                int i = 0;
                int id = 0;
                String name = "";
                String src = "";
                while (i < 5) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(q_question[i][0]) && TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(q_question[i][0])) {
                        id = Integer.parseInt(q_question[i][0]);
                    }
                    name = q_question[i][1];
                    src = q_question[i][2];

                    i++;
                }
                return ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance2(id, name, src);
            }else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return q_question.length;
        }
    }
```

My Fragment:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";
    private static final String ARG_RESOURCE_NAME = "resource_name";
    private static final String ARG_RESOURCE_SRC = "resource_src";

    private int id;
    private String Name;
    private String Src;

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance2(int id, String name, String src) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_RESOURCE_ID, id);
        args.putString(ARG_RESOURCE_NAME, name);
        args.putString(ARG_RESOURCE_SRC, src);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_RESOURCE_ID);
            Name = getArguments().getString(ARG_RESOURCE_NAME);
            Src = getArguments().getString(ARG_RESOURCE_SRC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);
        // assign our image's resource id here
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.question_image);
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.answer_one);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(Src));
        button.setText(Name);

        Log.e("test", id + Src +"//"+ Name); // There id always are 3, and src and name null

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no time to answer, but i managed it myself.
Removing `while (i < 5)` statement from `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` and leave all code in it outside statement, and all working.